# Python with .pdb files

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, chemistry

I am working on bio project. I have `.pdb` (protein data bank) file which contains information about the molecule.

I want to find out the following of a molecule in the `.pdb` file:

1. Molecular Mass.
2. H bond donor.
3. H bond acceptor.
4. LogP.
5. Refractivity.

Is there any module in Python which can deal with `.pdb` file in finding this? If not then can anyone let me know how can I do the same?

I found some modules like `sequtils` and `protienparam` but they don't do such things.

Comment: hmm that is ironic that you got downvoted

Comment: Just do `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` ... ;) sorry, couldn't resist.

Comment: @JohannesCharra its pdb file and not pdb module. protein data file(pdb)

Comment: Hey Johannes Charra - I just googled for this as well before finding this SO question. Most results are about the pdb debugger. This actually makes it hard to find .pdb files; I had to modify the query and still find mostly bad results. And by doing that answer, you also made it harder for others to find useful parts ... :(

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it fits your needs, but [Biopython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page) looks like it might help.

Answer (score 2):

`PDB` file also outputs an `XML` file `PDBML` that can be easily parsed using an `xml` parsing library

```
http://pdbml.pdb.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

A pdb file can contain pretty much anything.
A lot of projects allows you to parse them. Some specific to biology and pdb files, other less specific but that will allow you to do more (setup calculations, measure distances, angles, etc.).

I think you got downvoted because these projects are numerous: you are not the only one wanting to do that so the chances that something perfectly fitting your needs exists are really high.

That said, if you just want to parse pdb files for this specific need, just do it yourself:

- Open the files with a text editor.
- Identify where the relevant data are (keywords, etc.).
- Make a Python function that opens the file and look for the keywords.
- Extract the figures from the file.
- Done.

This can be done with a short script written in less than 10 minutes (other reason why downvoting).

Comment: Unfortunately the answer by user1940040 is not helpful. People don't want to be told "it can be done on your own". That would defeat the point of SO too.

Comment: I bet even a good programmer would need much more than 10minutes, especially with the new pdbx format